# Values for private method return in Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, junit5

I have a similar methods in my service as shown below:

```
public List<ProductDTO> findById(final int id) {
    final List<String> categoryList = getCategoryById(id);
    final List<UUID> productUuidList = 
        productRepository.findAllUuidByCategoryIdIn(categoryList);
    return getProductDTOList();
}

private static List<String> getCategoryById(final int id) {

    // code omitted
    return ...
}
```

I have a Unit Test for `findById` method as shown below.

```
@Test
public void test_findByZoneOffset() {

    List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    // code omitted (fill categoryList with proper values)

    final List<UUID> productUuidList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        productUuidList.add(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    when(productRepository.findAllUuidByCategoryIdIn(categoryList))
        .thenReturn(productUuidList);

    // code omitted
    

    final List<ProductDTO> productDTOList = productService.findById(5);
}
```

However, I cannot create `categoryList` as the same values returned by `getCategoryById()` method as it is private method. On the other hand, as there is no service or repository call in that private method, I do not want to call it from Unit Test method and just want to create a mock `categoryList` and make `categoryList` in `findById` method is the same. So, how can I do this?

Comment: Does this help https://www.baeldung.com/powermock-private-method

Comment: @SusanMustafa Thanks a lot Mustafa, but I need a solution without using an extra library, etc. Only using Junit and Mockito

Comment: Is the code above for `findById` the actual code you're testing? The `productUuidList` variable is never used.

Comment: @TimMoore Sorry, the code omitted (I updated now). So, `findById` is the actual code that I test.

Comment: @Henry I still don't get it. Why does `findById` define the `productUuidList` variable at all?